# MonoTouch: Enable Multisampling in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, xamarin.ios, opengl-es-2.0, opentk

Is there any way to activate multisampling with MonoTouch and OpenGL ES 2.0?
I can't find the apple extension in the framework, so i think it's not implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions like `glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleAPPLE` and `glResolveMultisampleFramebufferAPPLE` are not *presently* included in MonoTouch's OpenGL bindings. I'm not sure if they are included in the latest OpenTK bits.

Anyway whenever you find missing pieces you should fill a bug report (enhancement) on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com That will ensure you get notified on the progress of the bug/enhancement request.

**UPDATE**: MonoTouch 5.2.3 (stable) has been released and includes OpenTK 1.0 (which defines the mentioned symbols).

Comment: I'm wondering about this, because the multisampling is supported since iOS 4.0. Maybe i can invoke the method call with C#.

Comment: Yes, you can likely add the p/invoke inside your own application and use them. Most of the MonoTouch code wrt OpenGL is opensource (OpenTK) so interop should not be overly complicated.

Comment: Please note that MonoTouch uses a forked version of OpenTK that is closed-source. While most of the code is similar, there are a few significant differences: (a) upstream OpenTK includes all official OpenGL ES extensions, whereas MonoTouch doesn't; (b) upstream OpenTK uses strongly-typed enums, whereas MonoTouch uses the 'All' enum. There is little upstream OpenTK can do to improve the situation (the closed-source nature of the fork and the cost of MonoTouch are prohibitive).